# Full-Text search in Sql server with multiple tables and ranking

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search, dotnetnuke, ranking

We have a website which is running on DNN 7.1 with SQL server. We implemented full text search to show search results. We need to search several tables and show the results to the user. Right now the implementation is user enters search word(s) and clicks search, the code behind creates several threads to search different tables, and merge the data. Currently we are using contains predicate, issue with this is, there is no ranking and sometimes after the merge the results on the first page are not the best matches. I thought that I can use containstable and order the results by ranking but I read ranking doesn't have any meaning by itself, it merely tells which one best matches in the current resultset. But in my scenario I have multiple resultsets, how will I know which are best matches across multiple resultsets. Or am I going about this wrong way? What is a good way to handle this scenario? We need to improve the response time along with better results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is how we implemented full text searching across multiple tables:

1) create a new table to store the primary keys of the other tables in each column, another column to store the string concatenated values of all the search fields from each table, and another column to store the checksum value of the concatenated values.

2) implement the FTI on this new table, and create a job that regularly syncrhonizes/updates the concatenated search values only if the binary_checksum value is different

3) use the contains predicate on this new table and based on the results, join back to their corresponding tables based on the primary keys returned.